# How could I do a massive install of a PrestaShop module?

Tags: ftp, prestashop-1.6

I have a problem, I have to do a massive install of a custom PrestaShop module on 1500 e-commerce, but I don't know if this is possible, I was thinking to include a file called `install.php` and run through `a.sh`, this file may contain the next.

For example:

```
<?php    
    include "meli.php";
    $meli = new Meli();
    $meli->install();    
?>
```

I called this file and initially, nothing happened so I check the possible reason and was:

```
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
exit;
```

So I commented this and run it again but this show me this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Module' not found in
>  /home/dev2al5/public_html/modules/meli/meli.php on line 7

Does someone know how I can do this process?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I would do 3 things in the SH script:

- Copy of the modules files in each site in the modules folder
- Copy of a sql file containing the instructions to be executed
- Calling a URL present in each module that would execute the SQL and then delete the SQL file in question

Regards

Comment: Thanks so much, but can you give me an example, please.

Comment: You must install the module on a shop, then recover the installed folder, and create the SQL file. All must be put in the folder.

Then you launch the command:
cp -R pathname_path file_path_of_destination_folder

And finally a little php script that calls in curl installation url on each shop

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but can you show me how you would create the SQL file? Thanks again for your help and patience.

Comment: Just take the one present in the module (if there is one)